# St_within for getting the 10 mile radius MBR mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get data within 10 miles and I tried as mysql example like:

```
set @lat=16.7792468;
set @lng=96.1514016;
set @dist = 10;
set @rlon1 = @lon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69); 
set @rlon2 = @lon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69); 
set @rlat1 = @lat-(@dist/69); 
set @rlat2 = @lat+(@dist/69);
```

And I use this query to select data from database within 10 miles:

```
select
    *
from
    restaurants
where
    st_within((@rlng1, @rlat1), (@rlng2, @rlat2))
order by
    st_distance(@lng, @lat)
limit
    10;
```

But i got this error:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I don't know what is wrong or missing. Any suggestion welcome^^

[Reference link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Should not it be `st_within(POINT(@rlng1, @rlat1), POINT(@rlng2, @rlat2))` in where clause?

Also, [st_distance](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) expects two geometry objects, but lat + lng supplied.